Not able to preview pdf document in flutter
Align(
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, -0.47),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: FFButtonWidget(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await launchURL(
                                    'https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://library.fibairef.basketball/images/documents/c829e9848744ac644c5c63feb45f3115/FIBA_TableOfficialsManual_v6_0_2024_en.pdf');
                              },
                              text:
                                  'FIBA MANUAL FOR TABLE OFFICIALS (Version 6.0 - Valid as of February 2024)',
                              icon: FaIcon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.solidFilePdf,
                              ),
                              options: FFButtonOptions(
                                width: () {
                                  if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointSmall) {
                                    return 300;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointMedium) {
                                    return 600;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointLarge) {
                                    return 700;
                                  } else {
                                    return 900;
                                  }
                                }()
                                    .toDouble(),
                                height: () {
                                  if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointSmall) {
                                    return 40;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointMedium) {
                                    return 50;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointLarge) {
                                    return 60;
                                  } else {
                                    return 70;
                                  }
                                }()
                                    .toDouble(),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                iconPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                color: Color(0xFFFFE300),
                                textStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                    .titleSmall
                                    .override(
                                      fontFamily: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                          .titleSmallFamily,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: () {
                                        if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                            kBreakpointSmall) {
                                          return 20;
                                        } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)
                                                .width <
                                            kBreakpointMedium) {
                                          return 24;
                                        } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)
                                                .width <
                                            kBreakpointLarge) {
                                          return 28;
                                        } else {
                                          return 32;
                                        }
                                      }()
                                          .toDouble(),
                                      letterSpacing: 0.0,
                                      useGoogleFonts: GoogleFonts.asMap()
                                          .containsKey(
                                              FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                  .titleSmallFamily),
                                    ),
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  width: 1.0,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

The document size is around 65mb... i gives the error couldn't preview the file error.
I have been able to preview other files with lesser size using the same command.
Is there another way to preview this doc or is downloading the only option ?
My requirement is user much initially be able to preview the document on clicking the button and then have an option to download the same later.

This is a limitation of Google Drive preview functionality & happens even if you open the same link from a web browser. This is not related to Flutter and you may get better responses to your answer if you update the post with an appropriate title related to google drive.

If you are looking for alternatives to viewing the pdf in flutter you may directly launch the URL using url_launcher package like below instead of trying google docs embedded view.
launchURL('https://library.fibairef.basketball/images/documents/c829e9848744ac644c5c63feb45f3115/FIBA_TableOfficialsManual_v6_0_2024_en.pdf')
